# How to disable automatic retries of failed Metaflow tasks?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, netflix-metaflow

By default, MetaFlow retries failed steps multiple times before the pipeline errors out. However, this is undesired when I am CI testing my flows using pytest-- I just want the flows to fail fast. How do I temporarily disable retries (without hard-coding `@retry(times=0)` on all steps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it with by setting the `METAFLOW_DECOSPECS` environment variable: `METAFLOW_DECOSPECS=retry:times=0`.

This temporarily decorates all steps with `@retry(times=0)`-- unless they are already decorated, in which case this won't override the hard-coded retry settings.

Source: @Ville in the MetaFlow Slack.